# Python Qt SpinBox to update when out of focus

Tags: python, pyqt, qspinbox

I am trying to get a QSpinBox to only send the new value when it changes from focused to unfocused so that it doesn't send an update every time a user changes a digit.

Currently it looks like this

```
self.specificBox.valueChanged.connect(self.setspecificValue)
```

I tried to change it to

```
self.specificBox.editingFinished.connect(self.setspecificValue)
```

but that didn't work

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please show what you have done so far? Because the [`editingFinished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#editingFinished) signal is exactly what you are looking for and should work as intended.

Comment: change to  `self.specificBox.editingFinished.connect(lambda: self.setspecificValue(self.specificBox.value()))`

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks a lot, that worked just fine. Could you explain the difference please?